# How to list file names in a folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I have folder structure like this.

```
docs/doc1.html
docs/doc2.html
docs/spec1.html
index.html
```

I want to inject to `index.html` with `<ul>`, just file names (without extension) in `docs` folder. How can I do that?

Comment: No, but it IS possible with PHP, which might be what you mean. Try to provide more context about what you're trying to accomplish and what you have available.

Comment: Files on the server? Or on the client? (Neither is possible with in-browser JS, though)

Comment: @Walkerneo, PHP? Why did you pick PHP from all other languages? :)

Comment: @gdoron, I just assumed it's what he would be using if he's just starting out.

Comment: Yes, I'm new. So I have no idea about PHP. Just know some JS. I'll create another question topic to know how it's possible with PHP.

Comment: Don't create new questions yet. First, edit this one and make the clarifications you've been asked. As it's now, it's fairly unclear. We don't know where the folder is and we're not sure while the file API cannot be used.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I edited.

Comment: You edited and didn't provide any of the request info. Instead, you pushed your further question here. Sorry, but this is not a real question.

Comment: This is still unclear. For what purpose do you want to list the files? Why are you using javascript and HTML if you don't have clients?

Comment: I'll move it to server later. I just want to work in local for now.

Comment: @Imrahil. And the server will be using... C#\Java\PHP? you should learn some more about programming server-clients applications.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, you can't access the machine files with javascript.

You can suggest this feature to the browsers, I'm going to suggest give me free money to my bank.

Comment: Even without node.js or something like that?

Comment: @Imrahil, Haha, that's tricky - I don't think anyone here thought of that. Node.js runs server side and would be able to do it. Are you using node.js?

Comment: @Imrahil. Please tell us your master plan, why do you need this? I think this will be helpful...

Comment: I just want to list file names and inject them to an html file within <li> elements.

Comment: @Imrahil. The server files or the clients files? do you have a server? if you do what language are you using?

Comment: @Imrahil, OK, it sounds like you're doing this server-side, in which case, this is definitely possible. What server-side language are you using? Some common ones are PHP, Python, and Node.js. You mentioned Node.js, so is it possible that you're using Node.js with a templating engine perhaps?

Comment: In server files. I haven't a server. I use Windows. Also WAMP installed but I don't know PHP. I wrote JS beceause of don't know PHP.

Comment: I didn't use node.js before, could give me a link or start point how can I do that, looks like I need to learn too thing.

Comment: @Imrahil. In server files but you don't have a server. Doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: I mean with server files, it's local. There's nothing about client.

Comment: @Imrahil. I got confused even more. You don't have clients? then why do you use javascript and HTML? you should use something like C#\java\PHP\C++... not javascript.

Comment: Sorry for mistelling. I edited first post. I think now more clear what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only is not possible, However, you may need a Java applet or ActiveX component but those solutions will face the compatibility with users browsers.
In ActiveX, users must use Windows. For Java Applets users must has JVM on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can send HTTP request to a Web Server and receive JSON or XML response with required data. But you need a web server first :-). If you use node.js, have a look on http://blog.rassemblr.com/2011/04/a-working-static-file-server-using-node-js/